Newly created deployment pipeline is failing while fetching creds in Jenkins
I am willing to do deployment through bitbucket to Salesforce via Jenkins. However, I am facing an issue and my deployment is getting failed. I am unable to print 'passwordVariable' and 'usernameVariable' at stage 'Authenticate with Salesforce'. I have attached the screenshot of Jenkins log.
pipeline {
    
    agent any 

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage('Authenticate with Salesforce') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'sf-auth-creds', passwordVariable: 'SFDC_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'SFDC_USERNAME')]) {
                        println('sf-auth-creds!!')
                        println credentialsId
                        println passwordVariable
                        println usernameVariable
                        sh '''
                        sf login --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --clientid xyz123 --clientsecret xyz123 --username $SFDC_USERNAME --password $SFDC_PASSWORD
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }


Jenkins error output

It looks like, its not able to find the 'sf-auth-creds', is there anyways we can see the error in detail?
It looks like, its not able to find the 'sf-auth-creds', is there anyways we can see the error in detail?

Make a minimal reproduction and post the log. Not as a screenshot, as text.

To start credentialsId, passwordVariable and usernameVariable are not the variables; they are parameters of the function usernamePassword(...). Using it in the way as your example would likely result in an (NullPointer/Undefined?) Error/Exception.
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'sf-auth-creds', passwordVariable: 'SFDC_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'SFDC_USERNAME')]) {...}

Translated, you are telling Jenkins (via the pipeline) to set the password on the environment variable $SFDC_PASSWORD and the username on $SFDC_USERNAME within the ("scope" of the) braces {} using the credential with id: sf-auth-creds.
As an extra note: Jenkins will attempt to block credential leakage; so straight up printing the credentials password, and optionally username, will not be possible. Debugging this way would not be recommended as a debugging practice; please use the feedback from the sf login ... command instead; and/or test locally in a save environment (shell) using temporary and non production credentials.
